# How to intent Run application a hidden apk?

Tags: android

I have a game(apk) that hides with Unity

I want to open the game through an Android application

The problem is that when I check out this installer says it is not installed...

```
  String packageName = "com.altaretore.falcon";
            if (UserSetting.isPackageInstalled(ActDownload.this, packageName))
                startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName));
            else Toast.makeText(ActDownload.this, "App not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android

Please show your UserSetting.isPackageInstalled

Comment: And you could also try to start the app manually via apk.exe, so you can say that the package name start leads to an application start of the right activity

Comment: final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        if (intent == null) {
            return false;
        }
        List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        return list.size() > 0;

Comment: You can edit your question, so it gets well formatted.